# C++, windows (sometimes) white screen while taking an application screenshot

Tags: c++, winapi

I have an application function that triggers screenshot capture of the said application's window.

It goes like this:

```
    void PlatformWindow::captureScreenshot()
{
    WIN32Window *window = (WIN32Window*)&g_window;
    if (window) {
        HWND handle = window->getWindow();
        if (handle){
            RECT client_rect = { 0 };
            GetClientRect(handle, &client_rect);
            int width = client_rect.right - client_rect.left;
            int height = client_rect.bottom - client_rect.top;


            HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(handle);
            HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
            HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, width, height);
            SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);

            BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, hdcScreen, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

            BITMAPINFO bmp_info = { 0 };
            bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmp_info.bmiHeader);
            bmp_info.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
            bmp_info.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
            bmp_info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
            bmp_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
            bmp_info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

            int bmp_padding = (width * 3) % 4;
            if (bmp_padding != 0) bmp_padding = 4 - bmp_padding;

            BYTE *bmp_pixels = new BYTE[(width * 3 + bmp_padding) * height];;
            GetDIBits(hdc, hbmp, 0, height, bmp_pixels, &bmp_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

            BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfHeader;
            //Make screenshot name as a time
            time_t currentTime = std::time(NULL);
            std::ostringstream oss;
            auto tm = *std::localtime(&currentTime);
            oss << std::put_time(&tm, "%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M");
            auto time_string = oss.str();
            uint id = 0;
            std::string name = "screens\\" + time_string +"_0.bmp";

            //Loop over its indexes
            while(true){
                name = "screens\\" + time_string + "_" + std::to_string(id) +".bmp";
                if (!file_exists(name)){
                    break;
                }
                id++;
            }
            LPSTR fileName = const_cast<char *>(name.c_str());
            HANDLE bmp_file_handle = CreateFile(fileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

            // Add the size of the headers to the size of the bitmap to get the total file size
            DWORD dwSizeofDIB = (width * 3 + bmp_padding) * height + sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

            //Offset to where the actual bitmap bits start.
            bmfHeader.bfOffBits = (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + (DWORD)sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);

            //Size of the file
            bmfHeader.bfSize = dwSizeofDIB;

            //bfType must always be BM for Bitmaps
            bmfHeader.bfType = 0x4D42; //BM

            DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
            WriteFile(bmp_file_handle, (LPSTR)&bmfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
            WriteFile(bmp_file_handle, (LPSTR)&bmp_info.bmiHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
            WriteFile(bmp_file_handle, (LPSTR)bmp_pixels, (width * 3 + bmp_padding) * height, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

            //Close the handle for the file that was created
            CloseHandle(bmp_file_handle);

            DeleteDC(hdc);
            DeleteObject(hbmp);
            ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
            delete[] bmp_pixels;
        }
    }
}
```

And it works fine on several machines (Windows 10, XP and so on).
There is, however, a rare case on Windows 7 (and maybe others, I don't know if that's just a bad luck or whatever) that makes screenshot's blank. Just all white.
I ran some diagnosis and am pretty convenient that it, for sure, captures right window, but somehow it does not capture pixels well.

I dig deeper and found out, that whenever I set this option in windows ->  performance options -> "Adjust for best performance", it suddenly starts to work and a screenshot is positively taken (no more white screen, which is great).

What I am wondering right now is if I can somehow make my code better to cover up those situations since forcing user to change his Window's options is not an ideal scenario.

@EDIT:
I found out that this is the very option that makes it works, if I disable desktop composition, it works just fine.

Comment: Hi Ochmar, you can call [GetLastError()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) after GetDIBits or [BitBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-bitblt#return-value) function to see if there is an error code.